# Dealing with PHP code stored in database with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I started to use php a few hours ago. To begin studying I decided to bake a small web app focused in administration of code snippets, something pretty simple. All CRUD operations are working like a charm. The problem is:

User will add any sort of code in the application. It works when adding snippets in any programming language except PHP. When I use the Model::find() method the PHP code (from the snippet of code stored in database) is replaced by an empty string "" and I can't display it in the view.

Why is it happening and how can I solve it?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Its hard to debug this without knowledge of the code involved. Can you provide a link/listing of the exact code thats giving you trouble?

Comment: Is it getting lost going into the database or not being rendered?  After it's stored, can you see it in the tables using phpmyadmin?

Comment: Yes, it's stored in the database properly. It only "disappears" when its returned by the Model::find() method. I see an array, and where there should be a string like "<? echo 'Hello World'; ?>" there's only a "" (blank string);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably just not seeing the output in the browser because the browser tries to render the PHP `<? ?>` tags as HTML. You'll need to escape the code for output into the browser:

```
<pre><code><?php echo htmlentities($model['Model']['code']); ?></code></pre>
```

Comment: Yep, you're right. Problem solved!
I decided to use htmlspecialchars() instead of htmlentities(), it's less aggressive and will only sanitize the '&', '"', "'", '<', '>' characters.